# How to validate the result using selenium for a text present

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I need to mark a step pass or fail  a step after validating a text "shipping" available or not available in the page.

How can I mark the step pass or fail based availability.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Cucumber, I am assuming you are using JUnit and Java.

You need to use Assert of JUNIT/TestNG

You need to use Junit separately don't use cucumber JUnit API for asserting

You can use below dependencies

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now you can use assert as below:

```
Assert.assertEquals("shubham page", driver.getTitle());
```

Use below import

```
import org.junit.Assert;
```